# Regex matching or array search

Tags: java, regex, search, match

Suppose I have 60 words and I want to check if an input is any of these words


Which is faster:
1) making a regex and ORing the words in it
2) looping on an array and searching?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) This is something that is very easily tested.

Comment: I am still trying it but I am thinking it may depend on the input words themselves I donno?!

Comment: You can run the same test on different sets of test words.

Comment: @Doggynub If you just want to know the fastest way, assuming the list of 60 words is constant and you are going to vary the input, it would be to put all words in a `Set<String>` and test `.contains()` for each input string. This will compute a `hashCode` for each word in the `Set` at insertion time, and compare the input string to a known set of hash codes, in constant time.

Comment: @ColinMorelli this is fastest than brute and regex?

Comment: @merlin2011 The `Set.contains` will be a O(1) (constant time) operation. The brute force approach would be O(n) (linear time).

Comment: @ColinMorelli, Oh I know, but I was giving the running time if he iterated through his array and tested each of the `n` elements using O(1) time for each element.

Comment: @ColinMorelli oh ye true with hashset though I am still curious about the regex thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily test this yourself. Out of curiosity, I created a [test case](http://pastebin.com/n6B9ybhp) of four different scenarios:

1. `Pattern.matcher().matches()` with an on-demand `Pattern` instance (created for each run)
2. `Pattern.matcher().matches()` with a cached `Pattern` instance (created before all runs)
3. `String.equals()` for each element in the array, executed within a loop
4. `Set.contains()` on a cached `Set` (created before all runs)

**Data Set:** Input array containing 6000 randomly generated strings of 6 characters each. Each test was executed 10,000 times, the results of all runs were totaled and averaged.

The results (all times in ms - lower is obviously better). The first number is the total execution time of all 10,000 runs, the second number is the average of each run:

```
On-Demand Regex:    12934 (1.29 avg)
Pre-compile Regex:    458 (0.05 avg)
Loop:                  77 (0.01 avg)
Set.contains:           4 (0.00 avg)
```

Long story short: if you're going to use a regular expression (which you shouldn't) at least create and cache the `Pattern`. But assuming performance is what matters, you're not going to beat `Set.contains()` if you know the list of words ahead of time.

**Note** The On-demand regex test includes the cost of constructing the `StringBuilder` instance that is given to the `Pattern.compile()` method, so not necessarily all of the extra time is spent in regex compilation. The `Set.contains` test also has a slight advantage in that it's inlined, and avoids the extra stack creation of the method call. I modified the test to have that execute inside of a separate method, but it didn't materially affect the results.

Comment: Awesome results! How is the set searching so fast? Is there anywhere I can learn more about why set searching is faster than regex?